# New Source Network Address Translation Not Working after "conntrack -D --src-nat" Command

Tags: iptables

I configured a Linux server to have a secondary IP address and to use `iptables POSTROUTING` to perform source network address translation (SNAT) using the following commands.

```
ip addr add 10.11.198.99/25 dev eno3

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -o eno3 -s 10.11.198.45 -d 239.169.45.122 -j SNAT --to 10.11.198.99:60003
```

This all works great such that tcpdump shows that the source IP address `10.11.198.45` is replaced with `10.11.198.99`.

I then flushed the iptables NAT table to delete the `iptables POSTROUTING` chain rule, deleted the secondary IP address, and deleted the `conntrack -D --src-nat` flow entry using the following command

```
iptables -t nat -F 

ip addr del 10.11.198.99/25 dev eno3 

conntrack -D --src-nat
```

Afterwards, I added a new secondary IP address and added a new `iptables POSTROUTING` chain rule

```
ip addr add 10.11.198.79/25 dev eno3 

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -o eno3 -s 10.11.198.45 -d 239.169.45.122 -j SNAT --to 10.11.198.79:60003
```

At this point, I am unable to see the source network address translation take effect in that `tcpdump` shows the source IP address `10.11.198.45` is not replaced with `10.11.198.79`. It appears that the `conntrack -D --src-nat` command causes subsequent `iptables SNAT POSTROUTING` chain rule added to not work.

How do I get source network address translation to work again?